# I am able to update ui from another thread than main, in android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

I have following code in my method

```
//main thread here in activity, oncreate method
updateUiFromDbButton.setOnClickListener() {
           CoroutineScope(IO).launch {

                val textToSet = getStringFromDb()

                setText(textToSet)
            }
        }
```

```
and 
private fun setText(text: String) {
        val textView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        textView.text = text
    }
```

where getStringFromDb looks like this

```
suspend private fun getStringFromDb(): String {

        val allPersons = personDao.getAll()
        var totalNames: String = ""
        for (person in allPersons) {
            totalNames += (person.firstName)
                    .plus(" ")
                    .plus(person.lastName)
                    .plus(System.lineSeparator())
        }
        return totalNames
    }
```

What makes me really really confused is that the app doesn't crash and the textview is updated-
since the update is done in a io thread. Following code should work, where i have place the code in the withContext(Main)

```
updateUiFromDbButton.setOnClickListener() {

            CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
                val textToSet = getStringFromDb()
                    withContext(Main) {
                        setText(textToSet)
                    }
                    setText(textToSet)
            }
        }
```

and if omitted withConte(Main) i expect a crash.Can somebody explain this mystery for me?

Comment: I don't think calling main-thread-only functions from other threads is guaranteed to cause a crash every time. It's just a possibility, so you shouldn't do it.

Comment: I've seen UI poking from non-Main dispatchers work fine on an emulator, but crash on an actual device. I haven't checked, but it's possible the dispatcher isn't actually running the coroutine on a separate thread all the time, but you should treat it like it is

Comment: This is sort of a moot point anyway: `getStringFromDb` doesn't need to be run using an IO Dispatcher because a background dispatcher / thread should already be used internally to the `personDao.getAll()` call. So really you should just launch the coroutine using the Main Dispatcher anyway with something like `lifecycleScope.launch { ... }`. See, for example, https://medium.com/livefront/coroutine-misconceptions-whose-context-is-it-anyway-320c0b7adcc7 . But I agree with the previous comments: you are not guaranteed to see a crash, but you still shouldn't do what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin coroutines are actually not threads, they are execution blocks that can start in one thread, suspends and resume in another. So there is a possibility that your code is running on same UI thread all through. One thing you can check with is make your RoomDatabase not to accept calls from UI thread and see if the app crashes or not.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#your-first-coroutine